# DIY Linux email journalling system

Tags: linux, archive, email-server

I need to journal all incoming and outgoing emails. 
Currently emails are relayed by Edge transport server to Exchange 2010 email store.

I'd like to stick a linux server in-line with an MTA. It would archive locally then relay to the Exchange server.

I'd like to ask how Open Source mail servers perform on email indexing and searches 
(of a monolithic mail store file).

Do any of the following mail servers allow you to index email messages?

Qpopper
Open-Xchange
hMailServer
DBMail
Courier Mail Server
UW IMAP
Apache James
Cyrus IMAP
Exim
agorum core
IndiMail
Citadel
Postfix
Meldware Mail Server
Dovecot
Synovel Collabsuite
Zarafa
Zimbra
Sendmail

An email archive search GUI would also be nice for normal users. (not sysadmins using grep)
Does such a thing exist? I know about Squirrelmail, but that is more web based email application, not a GUI to an email archive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel if you don't have to. I linked you to [MailArchiva](https://www.mailarchiva.com/) in your [original question](https://serverfault.com/questions/364291/diy-linux-email-journalling-system/364294#364294). There is a free open-source edition if you're not interested in the commercial version... But the main points are there. It's a scalable, low-cost or free solution that has a good search interface and runs on Linux. [MailArchiva](https://www.mailarchiva.com/) also works with most mail servers.

If you're talking about mail journaling for legal/compliance/regulatory purposes, go with a purpose-built product.

Comment: Thanks! The original question was closed (even though I thought it was very relevant AND I re-edited it) It seems like MailArchiva is the only Open Source product in this area.

Comment: I voted to reopen the original.

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to do this with many pieces of software. I think most MTAs are capable of some kind of archiving based on configuration.

With Postfix, you can almost one-liner it: add an `always_bcc: your.address@archive.yourco.com` to the configuration file. If all mail goes through it, you'll be set. Dealing with the files after they've been delivered to the proper directory is an exercise for the asker or for another question.